# IntelliJ Idea live template annotated variable location

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

I am following [an article](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-template-variables.html) about live templates and noticed:

```
annotated("annotation qname")
```

> Creates a symbol of type with an annotation that resides at the specified location.

How do I specify location? I would like it to find occurences within file only but it searches outside too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The function always searches for annotated methods in the entire project.

The only way to change this would be to copy [the source code of the macro](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/template/macro/AnnotatedMacro.java) into your own plugin and to modify its logic as you see fit.